Regex to replace specific word in delimited list
I'm trying to get Java regex working to replace specific phrases in a comma delimited list.
For example I have a string of "BIG BOAT     , GREEN CAR,BIG BOAT, YELLOW TRUCK, BIG BOAT, AMAZON ECHO,      BIG BOAT    , BLUE CAR , BIG BOAT BLUE, TABLE, GLASSES, BIG BOAT" and I have the regex of
"(?:^|,\s*)BIG BOAT(?:$|[^,]*)"

This seems to work in most cases. It matches all exact instances of "BIG BOAT" (removing any leading or trailing whitespace, and correctly replaces the leading comma) in the above but incorrectly matches "BIG BOAT BLUE". I have to use strictly regex for this solution.

Please show example inputs that demonstrate the various edge cases and expected output for each.

(?:$|[^,]*) should be \s*(?:$|,).

Why not just use replaceAll with the word boundary meta character (\\b).
String s =  "BOAT, AMAZON ECHO, SAILBOAT,TABLE, EYEGLASSES,    GLASSES";
s = s.replaceAll("\\bBOAT\\b", "Foo");
System.out.println(s);
s = s.replaceAll("\\bGLASSES\\b", "Bar");
System.out.println(s);

prints
Foo, AMAZON ECHO, SAILBOAT,TABLE, EYEGLASSES,    GLASSES
Foo, AMAZON ECHO, SAILBOAT,TABLE, EYEGLASSES,    Bar

If you just want to replace the first occurrence you can use replaceFirst()

package exp;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexReplace {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "BOAT,";

    String regex = "BOAT(\\s*)?,?(\\s*)?";
    String replacement = "regex_test, ";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

    String resultString = matcher.replaceAll(replacement);

  }
    
}

this seems to work. output -
Original String: BOAT,  
Replaced String: regex_test, 

Is this what you were trying to achieve?
